# Add rel="xx" to jQuery a.link elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, rel

I use a little jQuery script to run a simple music player, but I'd like to add a rel="player" to the links in this jQuery script (the play/stop button for instance). This way I can exclude these rel="player" links from another jQuery script I use, because I don't want it to take the `rel="player"` elements into account.

I reckon this is fair simple but I don't really know how to to it.

[Here](http://hyker.be/cv/js/jquery.simpleplayer.min.js) is the jQuery script of the player, if it's ever necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take care of ALL the links. If you don't want all the links you need to be specific about which link you want.

```
$('a').each(function () {
   $(this).attr('rel', 'xx');
});
```

Comment: I guess it works but not in my case actually. I have this line of script (for another jquery script)

 `$('a').not("a[rel*=shadowbox]").each(function(i,el){`

Is it possible to actually add there a rel attribute? So I could just use this rel, and I wouldn't have to exclude others.

Comment: $('a:not[rel*=""]') is a little cleaner, but yup that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to add the rel to all the links

```
$('a').attr('rel','xx');
```